# Graphical representation of my .xml layout file is blank

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated my Android studio to AS -1.4 recently, after the update I cant see graphical design of my `.xml` files.

I cant figure out what went wrong but the `display` tab is blank but the `text` tab is having valid code in it.

-Can any one help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to pick the appropriate API level instead of Auto pick, or download latest API from SDK Manager.
2. Also Refresh your design page to view your changes.